# How to replace an old Windows 2003 SBS DC with a Win2008 Standard Edition DC?

Tags: domain-controller, windows

**Objective:**
Trying to replace a Windows 2003 SBS domain controller with a windows server 2008 Standard Edition Domain Controller.

**What I did:**
 used ADPREP. Then all user accounts and OUs are successfully replicated into the 2008 server. I have also managed to transfer all the DC roles (operations master,schema,pdc) into the Server 2008. 
I have also used NETDOM QUERY FSMO . It displayed  that all the roles transferred to the 2008 server.

**Problem:**

When I am trying to demote the windows 2003 SBS server using DCPROMO, the message is “No other Active Directory for this domain can be contacted”. I also tried shutting down the 2003 server. Users can login into the domain but they have trouble finding SHARED folders.
Can someone help me find out what I did wrong? Need a little push in the right direction here.

Comment: Did you move the [Global Catalog](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313994) also? And is the new server running [DNS](http://serverfault.com/questions/55060/an-active-directory-domain-controller-for-this-domain-could-not-be-contacted) in AD mode?

Comment: As an aside: You do realize that you will have to permanently shutdown the Windows 2003 SBS machine when you're done with this, don't you? All data on that server will need to be migrated off of the machine. Windows 2003 SBS cannot be used as a "member server" in an Active Directory domain.

Comment: Hi ! I am intending to shutdown the old DC and just re-install windows  standard edition for another server role once. 

Both the old DC and the new DC are GLOBAL Catalog and the New DC is also Running DNS.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "trouble finding shared folders"?

Answer (score 0):

Have all your clients been switched over for DHCP, DNS and WINS to the new Domain Controller?

Are you using DFS and if so, have you migrated the namespace across to the new DC with dfsutil? (Assuming DFS is supported on SBS - Suspect it isn't)

If you ping *domainname* from clients, do they all return the IP of the new server, and not the old one?